# Fuzzy Cognitive Maps

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am working on a project for prediction, using Fuzzy Cognitive Maps. I am new to data mining and want to learn about Fuzzy Cognitive Maps and its implementation. I also want to know what tools are required for this. I am beginner in this domain, so I need a little help to get started. I would be very grateful for help with some good resources and advice.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [competitive fuzzy cognitive maps](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Elpiniki_Papageorgiou/publication/220199753_A_new_methodology_for_Decisions_in_Medical_Informatics_using_fuzzy_cognitive_maps_based_on_fuzzy_rule-extraction_techniques/links/53f4c17f0cf2888a74911729.pdf)

Comment: Can you please elaborate.  Link-only answers are generally discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

We recently developed fcmpy library. Hopefully, you can find some answers there! You can use it for building FCMs, simulating them, creating interventions as well as optimizing or generating them using machine learning.

Article about the library is available here:
https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.12749v1

The package can be installed via pip
https://pypi.org/project/fcmpy/

Git repo
https://github.com/SamvelMK/FCMpy

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To learn about FCM, there are several youtube channels. I can mention some:

- [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r804UF8Ia4c)
- [MentalModeler](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HNEfGppZptU)

To easily work with FCM without diving into code, you may use [FCM Expert](https://sites.google.com/view/fcm-expert/home).